# logistic regression assumption of linearity of logit not met (SPSS)

Tags: logistic-regression, spss

I'm currently writing my master's thesis (I'm using SPSS for statistical analyses). One of my calculations is a logistic regression. These are the variables:

dependent variable: occupation (dichotomous, 1=yes, person has a job, 0= person is unemployed)
independent variable 1: self-stigmatization (mean value of a questionnaire,between 1 and 4, continuous).

Now my problem is that apparently there is no linear relationship between my independent variable and the log of my dependent variable (calculated using Box-Tidwell method). Obviously it's possible that there is no relationship between the two constructs in my data, but I've been asking myself, if there's another way to calculate a regression between these two variables if the assumptions for the logistic regression are not met? I just don't want to miss a valid (well, actually better fitting) option that I didn't know of yet...

Does anyone know a method or have any literature tips? Thanks for the help!

Comment: It sounds like your question is more about statistics than programming. If so, you'd do better asking it on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). StackOverflow is really just for programming questions. If your question *is* about programming, then you need to post some code and sample data. See [Ask] for more info.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I will do that!

Answer (score 0):

We need more info on the distributions of each of these variables and number of cases. One thought is whether transforming your independent variable might yield better results. If the mean value is normal, could you transform it into quartiles and see if you get a different/significant result?  Additionally, you could group your sample by another variable in your dataset and see if relationships arise.

*I would make this a comment but still need only one more point to do so!*